# Groupby on condition and calculate sum of subgroups

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

Here is my data:

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
z = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,1,2,2,3,3],'b':[3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 'c':[10,11,12,13,14,15,16]})
z

    a   b   c
0   1   3   10
1   1   4   11
2   1   5   12
3   2   6   13
4   2   7   14
5   3   8   15
6   3   9   16
```

## Question:

How can I do calculation on different element of each subgroup? For example, for each group, I want to extract any element in column 'c' which its corresponding element in column 'b' is between 4 and 9, and sum them all.

Here is the code I wrote: (It runs but I cannot get the correct result)

```
gbz = z.groupby('a')
# For displaying the groups:
gbz.apply(lambda x: print(x))


list = []

def f(x):
    list_new = []
    for row in range(0,len(x)):
        if (x.iloc[row,0] > 4 and x.iloc[row,0] < 9):
            list_new.append(x.iloc[row,1])
    list.append(sum(list_new))

results = gbz.apply(f)
```

The output result should be something like this:

```
    a   c
0   1   12
1   2   27
2   3   15
```

Comment: Start out by reading the docs. [This comparison](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/comparison_with_sql.html) with SQL may help you, even if you don't know what SQL is.

Comment: @dangom, Sure. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might just be easiest to change the order of operations, and filter against your criteria first - it does not change after the `groupby`.

```
z.query('4 < b < 9').groupby('a', as_index=False).c.sum()
```

which yields

```
   a   c
0  1  12
1  2  27
2  3  15
```

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Ah I didn't see they wanted `a` not in the index, one second.

Comment: Should be `z.query('4 < b < 9').groupby('a').c.sum()` not inclusive.
`

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
In [2379]: z[z.b.between(4, 9, inclusive=False)].groupby('a', as_index=False).c.sum()
Out[2379]:
   a   c
0  1  12
1  2  27
2  3  15
```

Or

```
In [2384]: z[(4 < z.b) & (z.b < 9)].groupby('a', as_index=False).c.sum()
Out[2384]:
   a   c
0  1  12
1  2  27
2  3  15
```

Comment: Op mentions groups... I'm wondering whether there's a possibility of a  difference in output doing the sum before groupby vs after.

Answer (score 1):

You could also `groupby` first.

```
z = z.groupby('a').apply(lambda x: x.loc[x['b']\
           .between(4, 9, inclusive=False), 'c'].sum()).reset_index(name='c')
z

   a   c
0  1  12
1  2  27
2  3  15
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use

```
z.groupby('a').apply(lambda x : sum(x.loc[(x['b']>4)&(x['b']<9),'c']))\
             .reset_index(name='c')
Out[775]: 
   a   c
0  1  12
1  2  27
2  3  15
```